# How to make a vehicle sense and obey traffic lights in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, vehicle

I am creating a traffic simulator and I have my vehicle and traffic light system working. My vehicle stops when the traffic light turns red, but it stops wherever it currently is instead of in front of the light, even when specifying a `range`.

I am building this project in unity3d with C#. Below is a part of my code.

- `material1` is the red traffic light.
- `range` is the minimum specified distance between vehicle current position and traffic light location.

```
if(!(m.CM.color.Equals(material1.color)) && (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, TrafficLightPosition <= range) ))     
{
    ApplySteer ();
    Drive (1);
    CheckWaypointDistance ();
    LerpToSteerAngle (); 
}
```

I heard about this unity feature called OnTriggerEnter/Exit/Stay, can someone please tell me if this will work in the traffic lights context?

Comment: Should probably add a tag stating what framework you're using and also include some of your existing code.

Answer (score -1):

You didn't specify a language/ engine, so I'll give a platform agnostic answer...

You could create a zone in front of the traffic light that says "stop here if the traffic light is red" to your vehicle when it is inside the zone, further vehicles approaching the traffic light will stop when they see that there is another car stopped directly in front of them.

Comment: I am sorry, I am implementing my project on unity3d and using C#.

Comment: In which case, the answer is more complex. You need two behaviours: One for preventing collisions with parked cars, and one for stopping when it "sees" a red light.